# Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for binary groups

Tags: statistics, matlab, hypothesis-testing

I am using Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for selecting data that distinguishes two groups. I have defined the group with the binary variables (0 and 1).

group = [1 0 1 1 1 0 0];
x =[2 3 4 5 2 -1 1];

I want to do kolmogorov test to identify whether x can distinguish 0 and 1 in the group. Is there any way that I can use matlab's kstest2 to do this? I couldn't find a way to get p-value based on group.

Can anyone help me in solving the problem?